# KGDB for nexus 5

Tags: android, kernel, kgdb

I'm debugging a kernel for Nexus 5. It's so buggy that the phone will never start normally, as there are many bugs. I'd like to debug it with KGDB via the audio jack (as it's a serial port). I've already learned how to compile the kernel to enable the kgdb, but still doesn't work, as I can't halt the kernel execution via minicom before it has a kernel panic. How can I make the KGDB work?

Comment: See if you can enable some sort of wait-for-connection?

Comment: I've tried to enable the boot option `kgdbwait`: `mkbootimg --base 0x00000000 --ramdisk_offset 0x02900000 --second_offset 0x00F00000 --tags_offset 0x02700000 --cmdline 'console=ttyHSL0,115200 androidboot.hardware=hammerhead user_debug=31 maxcpus=2 msm_watchdog_v2.enable=1` **kgdbwait** `kgdboc=ttyHSL0,115200 kgdbretry=4' --kernel zImage-dtb --ramdisk ramdisk.img -o boot.img`